# Filter gallery with multiple condition in powerapp

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I want to filter gallery with status = in progress or completed and created by me ,
below formula working for status but unable to add created by me filter

```
Sort(Filter("SPList", 'Status'.Value= "in progress"||'Status'.Value="completed "),Created,Descending)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me. Where `CurrentUser` is variable storing the Email of current user:

```
UpdateContext({ CurrentUser: User().Email })
Sort(Filter("SPList", 'Status'.Value = "in progress" || 'Status'.Value = "completed" && 'Created By'.Email = CurrentUser), Created, Descending)
```